# htaccess rewrite http://example.com to http://www.example.com but https://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

Using .htaccess rewrite, I'd like to have:

`http://example.com` redirect to: `http://www.example.com`
`https://www.example.com` redirect to: `https://example.com`

Which is the best way to do this?

I've started with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613173/htaccess-rewrite-http-example-com-to-http-www-example-com-but-https-www-ex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You saved the day again! Thank you